# spark-examples job failed on single node kubernetes cluster due to java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, google-compute-engine

I submitted sample spark (job provided in Spark code) to k8s cluster due to java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc. It would be very helpful if you can help me fix this issue.

**My environment:**

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 bionic image built on 2019-06-17
- 2 vCPUs 7.5 GB memory
- Cloud service: Google Coud Engine
- single master node only (no worker node)

**How to reproduce my issue:**

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.128.0.10:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.128.0.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
$ bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://10.128.0.10:6443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=yohei1126/spark:v2.3.3 \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --name spark-pi \
    local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.3.jar
```

**error log:**

- KubeDNS is working but name resolution might not be working well.

```
    $ kubectl logs spark-pi-67ed1ddda23e32799371677bf1e795c4-driver
    ...
    2019-06-24 08:40:16 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler
    cannot be instantiated
    ...
    Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation:
    [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [spark-pi-67ed1ddda23e32799371677bf1e795c4-driver]
    in namespace: [default]  failed.
    ...
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Try again
```

**How I installed k8s on clean ubuntu:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
$ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
$ cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
$ apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

I also installed Docker-ce since kubeadm requires it.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y docker-ce
```

**How I initialize cluster:**

- specified network address to --pod-network-cidr.

```
    $ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.128.0.0/20
    $ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    $ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
    $ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

    $ sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
    $ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
    $ kubectl taint nodes test-k8s node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

**How I created the docker image:**

- I used pre-built Spark tar.

```
$ wget http://ftp.meisei-u.ac.jp/mirror/apache/dist/spark/spark-2.3.3/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
$ tar zxvf spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
$ cd spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7
$ sudo bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r yohei1126 -t v2.3.3 build
$ sudo bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r yohei1126 -t v2.3.3 push
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to build single node Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntsu 18.04 LTS using minikube.

- machine type： n1-standard-4（4 vCPU, 15GB memory）
- Disk size：30GB
- CPU platform: Intel Haswell
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Docker v18.09.7
- minikube v.1.2.0
- kubectl v1.15.0

## Install Docker

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

## Install kubectl

```
$ sudo snap install kubectl --classic
```

## Install minikube

```
$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
  && chmod +x minikube
$ sudo install minikube /usr/local/bin
```

## Start kubernetes cluster

- Note: sample Spark job requires 8GB memory

```
$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none --cpu 4 --memory 8192
$ sudo mv /home/yohei/.kube /home/yohei/.minikube $HOME
$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube
```

## Create Kubernetes service account for Spark job

```
$ kubectl create serviceaccount spark
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default
```

## Check cluster IP address

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.128.0.11:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.128.0.11:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

## Run Spark job

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
$ wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.3.3/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
$ tar zxvf spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
$ cd spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7
$ bin/spark-submit \
  --master k8s://https://10.128.0.11:6443 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=yohei1126/spark:v2.3.3 \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --name spark-pi \
  local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.3.jar
```

## Check result

```
2019-07-02 08:57:56 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - State changed, new state: 
         pod name: spark-pi-e39a8e8f7faf3c9fa861ae024e93b742-driver
         namespace: default
         labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-d0860239ee0f4118aeb8fee83bd00fa2, spark-role -> driver
         pod uid: 01e8f4c0-ae85-4252-92f7-11dbdd2e2b0d
         creation time: 2019-07-02T08:57:10Z
         service account name: spark
         volumes: spark-token-bnm7w
         node name: minikube
         start time: 2019-07-02T08:57:10Z
         container images: yohei1126/spark:v2.3.3
         phase: Succeeded
         status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=docker://c8c7584c7b704b8f2321943967f84d58267a9ca9d1e1852c2ac9eafb76816dc1, image=yohei1126/spark:v2.3.3, imageID=docker-pullable://yohei11
26/spark@sha256:d3524f24fe199dcb78fd3e1d640261e5337544aefa4aa302ac72523656fe2af1, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=s
park-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=ContainerStateTerminated(containerID=docker://c8c7584c7b704b8f2321943967f84d58267a9ca
9d1e1852c2ac9eafb76816dc1, exitCode=0, finishedAt=Time(time=2019-07-02T08:57:56Z, additionalProperties={}), message=null, reason=Completed, signal=null, startedAt=Time(time=2019-07-02T
08:57:21Z, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={}), waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={})]
2019-07-02 08:57:56 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - Container final statuses:
         Container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
         Container image: yohei1126/spark:v2.3.3
         Container state: Terminated
         Exit code: 0
2019-07-02 08:57:56 INFO  Client:54 - Application spark-pi finished.
2019-07-02 08:57:56 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2019-07-02 08:57:56 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9cbaba30-9277-4bc9-9c55-8acf78711e1d
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
spark-pi-e39a8e8f7faf3c9fa861ae024e93b742-driver   0/1     Completed   0          43m
yohei_onishi@test-k8s:~$ kubectl logs spark-pi-e39a8e8f7faf3c9fa861ae024e93b742-driver
...
Pi is roughly 3.141395706978535
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share us what are the entries related to kube-system logs in Stackdriver Logging according this documentation [1]?. I saw the same issue before and it was related to 403's permissions error or IO timeout.

Also you can try to re-create the nodepool. It can fix the issue.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/legacy-stackdriver/logging

Comment: It is customary to ask for clarification / additional information from the original author in the comments section rather than the answers section.

Comment: I did not use GKE